# Simple Harmonic Motion of sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

> Problem: A solid sphere of radius 15cm is pivoted at a point on its
>   surface. It is held so that the diameter passing through both the
>   pivot and the center of the sphere makes a 0.15 radian angle with the
>   vertical. The sphere is released at time = 0.10s.
>
> Find the velocity of the bottom of the sphere at time $t$ = 0.4s.

The equation for the angle between the radius to the pivot and the vertical as a function of time I found:

$\theta_0 = 0.15$

$\theta = 0.15cos(\omega t - \phi)$

$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{g}{7/5R}}$

$\phi = 0.683130511$

Therefore:

$\theta = 0.15cos(6.8313 t - 0.683130511)$

The angular velocity is given by: $\omega = \frac{d^{2}\theta}{dt^{2}} = 1.0247\sin(0.683131 - 6.8313t)$

$\frac{v}{r} = \omega$

$r_b = 0.3cm$

Solving for $v$ I get 0.273m/s. 
The answer given is 0.14m/s.

What error have I made?

Comment: check value of your angle relation at t=0

Comment: what do you mean? The sphere is released at t = 0.10s. So I calculated the phase shift.

Comment: Hi Quaxton and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @QuaxtonHale yes my mistake

Comment: check definition of angular velocity instead

Comment: I couldn't resist having a quick go at this, and I get the same result as you do. I note that the given answer is about right for the velocity of the **centre** of the sphere. I wonder if there's a mistake in the question.

Comment: I agree with @JohnRennie - the question asks for velocity of the bottom which is twice the velocity of the center. Maybe your "mistake" was believing the answer key...

Comment: How did you find that equation for the angle?

Answer (score 0):

I've got **v(0.4)= 3.066 m/s**

I'will use [physical pendulum, circular geometry - hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pencir.html#c1)
with data : radius 0.15 cm , g=9.8 m/s/s
The period T for a sphere is 0.09197 sec  (last value in the page)
(is more than 10 times faster than a simple pendulum of length 30 cm)
I get $$\theta(t)=\theta_{max}*cos((t-t_{0})*2\pi/T)$$

With the substitution of sin by cos and t by $t-t_0$ we get a maximum 0.15 at time 0.10 s

and at the [sagemath](https://cloud.sagemath.com) 
I get two graphs $\theta$
|--> 0.150000000000000*cos(10.8724014960424*pi*(2*t - 0.200000000000000))
and $\theta(0.10)$ = 0.150000000000000

and  $v(t)=d\theta/dt$
|--> -3.26172044881273*pi*sin(10.8724014960424*pi*(2*t - 0.200000000000000))
and **v(0.4) m/s=  -3.06576728129694**

```
t,b,g,L,tmax,tstart=var('t,b,g,L,tmax,tstart')
theta = function('theta', t)
theta1 = function('theta1', t)

#b=g/L
#assume(g>0)
#assume(L>0)
L=0.15    ## Length of string
tstart=0.10
g=9.8 ## accelaration due to gravity
tmax=0.15
##### Pendulum's Time Period: ############
#
T=0.091976

theta(t)=tmax*cos((t-tstart)*2*pi/T)
theta
theta(tstart)

#theta1(t)=0.15*cos(6.8313*t-0.683130511)  ## the one of OP
a=plot(theta, 0.10,1.1)
a.show(aspect_ratio=0.5)
#b=plot(theta1, 0.10,1.1)
#b.show(aspect_ratio=0.5)

v=diff(theta,t)
v
print"v(0.4) m/s= ",0.30*v(0.4).n()

b=plot(v, 0.10,1.1)
b.show()
```

[image]